# jquery upwards sliding panel at bottom of large image div

Tags: jquery, css

I need to set up a jquery function to make a panel to slide up from the bottom of a div when the div is clicked. What i currently have is this:

```
    $(function() {

  var open = false;

  $('.header-wrapper').click(function() {

      if(open === false) {
          $('.header-controls').show();
          $('.header-controls').animate({top:'350px', height:'50px'}, 800, function() {
            //callback
          }); 

          $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');

          open = true;

      } else {

          $('.header-controls').animate({top:'400px', height:'0px'}, 800, function() {
            $('.header-controls').hide(); 
          }); 
          $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');

          open = false;

      }

  });     

});
```

Unfortunately this only works when the sliding panel is set to position: fixed - which means as soon as the page scrolls, the panel (if open) goes off with it. How can i set the same thing up, but ensuring that the panel stays with the associated div?

Here is a quick jsfiddle to show how it's currently working: http://jsfiddle.net/nAX43/5/ (just click on the image then scroll down to see the problem)...

Cheers!

Comment: give a demo in jsfiddle with the current script

Comment: done... added to the original question.

Comment: slideUp() is to hide an object rather than reveal it, it seems - i *think* there's a way to reverse the behaviour, but i couldn't get it to work. If you have an idea, could you show us on the jsfiddle? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine if you change it to `position: absolute` in the class below,

```
.header-controls {
    position: absolute;
    top:400px;
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    background-color:rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.5);
    color:#ccc;
    z-index: 5000;
    display:none;
}
```

see demo. http://jsfiddle.net/nAX43/7/

Comment: nice, simple answer. thanks Nithin. You're a gentleman and a scholar.